# Java Collections by user input

Tags: java, collections

In java collections 
I should get user input as integers and sort it in Ascending order.

```
import java.util.*;   
import java.io.*;
class ArrayToCollection{ 

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.println("How many elements you want to add to the array: ");
      int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
      int[] num = new int[n];
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         num[i] = in.readLine();
      }
     TreeSet<String> setA =new TreeSet<String>();
     setA.add(num);
     System.out.println(setA.contains(num));
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: (Please don't downvote too much. The OP is new on SO and showed what he tried.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("How many elements you want to add to the array: ");
int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
System.out.println("enter numbers : ");
TreeSet<String> setA = new TreeSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    setA.add(in.readLine());
}

System.out.println(setA.toString());
```

you don't need array int

Comment: **Brian Tompsett** Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class ArrayToCollection{ 

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 System.out.println("How many elements you want to add to the array: ");
 int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
 System.out.println("enter numbers : ");
 TreeSet<Integer> setA = new TreeSet<Integer>();
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     setA.add(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
 }

 System.out.println(setA.toString());
}
}
```